# Безопасность, cookie, бекенд, Expressjs,

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookie, безопасность

В офф документации сказано что нужно использовать модули `cookie-session` или `express-session` которые создают сессии и для работы требуют совместимые сессионные хранилища. До этого в проекте было уже реализовано JWT авторизация, но управление куками(запись в них токена) происходит в контроллере. Обошлись без сессий. В проекте уже используется библиотека для связи с БД. Добавление еще одной выглядит как костыль. 
Сейчас главная проблема в том что пользователи с других устройств не могут авторизоваться на сайте- запрос блокируется и в панели разработчика в деталях запроса светит ошибка - `Provisional headers are shown`

1. Необходимость подключать еще одну библиотеку только для хранения сессий в той же БД связь с которой уже установлено другой библиотекой - нормально ли это?
2. В офф документации ничего не сказано про альтернативу сессий - токены. Как мне по правильному настроить безопасность в простейшем виде? Чтобы все пользователи имели возможность авторизоваться на сайте.

Миддлвари подключены следующие:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(nocache());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: 'GET,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200
}));
app.use(router);
app.use(compression());
app.use(helmet(some options));
```

Что дает мне настройку следующих заголовков(21шт):

```
Surrogate-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';script-src 'self';object-src 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=360000
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Set-Cookie: refreshToken=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: accessToken=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 18
ETag: W/"12-4CbZ3C1+6XJusRP57OSWRG8lXno"
Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2022 00:24:49 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

механизм защиты от xss и csrf атак еще не реализован.

Предлагайте любые дельные замечания. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Provisional headers are shown - это не ошибка. Должен быть ещё какой-то текст с ошибкой. Меня смущает наличие localhost:3000 в cors. Вряд ли у вас сайт поднят на телефоне.

Comment: А зачем вам сессии или бд для хранения состояния, если у вас jwt токены?

Comment: Danil, я тоже упорно не понимаю зачем мне сессии, ведь у меня уже есть JWT токены

Comment: Alexey, высвечивает - `POST http://localhost:5001/auth/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Я пробовал по IP адресам настраивать фронт и бэк но тогда вообще почему-то не работало(в смысле не работало даже на главной машине что localhost). Фронт работает на http://localhost:3000, а бэк на http://localhost:5001

Comment: Кажется вам не помешает узнать что же значит localhost